# How can we show that $f_1f_2...f_k=0$ iff $\exists j$ st $f_j=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

Assume $V$ is an n dimensional vector space.  $f_1,...f_k\in V^*,v_1,...,v_k\in V$ Define the symmetric k tensor $f_1f_2...f_k(v_1,..,v_k)=\Sigma_{\delta\in S_k}f_{\delta 1}(v_1)...f_{\delta_k}(v_k)$
How can we show that $f_1f_2...f_k=0$ iff $\exists j$ st $f_j=0$?

Comment: It's a bit of a jumble.  What are the $f_j$? Functions? What are the $v_i$?  Arguments? Scalars?  You seem to be defining a multivariable function using sums of permutations of the $f_j$ applied to the $v_i$, but you've been very sparing with parentheses.  Some words of explanation (does $f_j = 0$ mean identically zero on all arguments?) would be helpful.

Comment: $f_i v_j \equiv f_i(v_j)$ ? Then write it.

Comment: So, from the edits, the $f_j$ are linear functionals on $V$.  The $k$-tensor is thus a multilinear form.  Presumably we are asked to show this multilinear form is identically zero iff some "component" $f_j$ is the zero functional.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Suppose not. Reduce to the case where the $f_i$ are linearly independent. Now choose $v_j$ so that $f_i(v_j)=\delta_{i,j}$.

P.S. The standard notation would be $\text{Sym}(f_1\otimes \dots \otimes f_k)(v_1,\dots,v_k)$.